# How can I read only one thing in from a textfile?

Tags: java

I can read in from the file and am able to change the amount of lines given by changing the number in the for loop but I don't want all the numbers in my file displayed side by side like that. I need them all going down one by one randomly.

```
public class Assignment2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        // Read in the file into a list of strings
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("textfile.txt"));
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        String line = reader.readLine();

        while( line != null ) {
            lines.add(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        // Choose a random one from the list
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int p = 0; p<3; p++)
        {
            String randomString = lines.get(r.nextInt(2));
            System.out.println(lines);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you mean.

Comment: the output is all the numbers side by side and then makes however many columns of that i assign. i need to have the numbers going down randomly until there is 20.    My txt file is  20  'enter' 10 'enter' 15 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to print is

```
String randomString = lines.get(r.nextInt(2));
System.out.println(randomString);
```

To display only the first 20 random lines from this list of maybe 100

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

   int rowNum = r.nextInt(lines.size ());
   System.out.println(lines.get(rowNum);
}
```

Comment: now how can i make this to only read the amount of numbers in the text file? sorry I'm a little new to this

Comment: LPT: Learn to communicate more clearly.  What do you mean?

Comment: Is my for in the wrong spot? Im trying to only read in 20 random numbers from a list of 100

Comment: Thanks i appreciate it and sorry about not being able to understand me at first

Comment: So I'm stuck again. Instead of printing the 20 numbers out how do i put them into an input file? tried a few things

Comment: have you had a look at FileWriter ?

Comment: I did and still trying to set it up but im assuming im doing something small wrong

Comment: Time for a new question then.